# Unable to pass django model object to serializer

Tags: django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to pass a django model object to a field in a serializer that is for a foreign key field in the model. However, I get the error: "Object of type AuthorUser is not JSON serializable."

Here is the model the serializer is for:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(AuthorUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    edited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ready_for_edit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the serializer (author is the field specifically that is giving me trouble):

```
class CreateArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'author']
```

And here is the view that has the code that causes the error (the POST method is the part that causes the error):

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def articles(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        articles = Article.objects.all()
        serializer = CreateArticleSerializer(articles, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            author = AuthorUser.objects.get(id=request.data['author'])
            request.data['author'] = author
            print(request.data)
            serializer = CreateArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=401)
```

Any help is appreciated! Just to let you know, when creating these articles using an id, it works, however, it creates a new field in Article called author_id. Then when I try to access author it gives me author_id so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your serializer as follows:

```
class CreateArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=AuthorUser.objects.all(), 
             slug_field='id')

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'author']
```

Now if you will pass id in your view while calling serializer it will create the object of model. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I'll give this a shot when I get home from school. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: sure waiting for your response.

Comment: Sadly it is still retrieving the author id when using the article serializer. Here is the creation serializer upon creating a new article: OrderedDict([('title', 'asdfafsd'), ('body', 'asfafssdf'), ('author', <AuthorUser: myemail@gmail.com>)]). However, upon fetching the same article using a GET request and the same serializer, it returns the id again. *upon furhter testing I have found that the serializer simply sets author to whatever I pass to the author field, string, slug, or else

Comment: So you want to get author name instead of id while using a GET request?

Comment: No I'm expecting to get a serialized author object because the author field of the article is a foreign key field

Comment: And when I create the article I use the id as a slug related field and when I print the data being passed it shows it is an author object yet when I retrieve it is is just the author id